# How does Chromium manage work on different releases in version control?

Tags: git, chromium

I have noticed that there are no branches that reflect a particular version - there's just the main branch and a few other branches, but they are not related to a specific version.

How do they manage to patch the current stable release and work on the alpha at the same time without having different branches? Or are they hidden?

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src

Comment: Are you sure the repository is their real development repository and not one that was cleaned up to show the final result?

Comment: @phd Chromium developers use Chromium repo quite differently. The Chromium repo will confuse new developers because of the way master branch works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main or master branch that you are referring to is canary build--for development purposes only. Canary builds are not tested and are generally released daily. So it has been known to be very buggy.

Chromium versions are categorized as tags. You can use the following command from your Chromium repo to pull all the tags:

```
git fetch --tags
```

Use the following command to show the list of tags available:

```
git tag
```

Then to checkout a version of Chromium:

```
git checkout tags/1.2.3.4
```

where `1.2.3.4` is one of the versions listed in the tags. So Chromium developers checkout a stable version and then make changes to the source code and bump the version in `src/chrome/VERSION` file. That file reflects the version of the current Chromium build. Then they create a corresponding tag and push the tag.

You can find all the version numbers here: https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/releases

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to know how it's possible though. I mean, tags only mark a specific point in history (unless I'm missing something). If they don't use multiple branches like 100.x.x, 101.x.x etc. - how are they able to maintain multiple major versions at the same time with one linear master branch? #ifdefs?

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk To answer that question, it's better to refer to this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/main/docs/process/release_cycle.md#release-cycle If I copy-paste those data there, things might change in the future, so there are chances it will be outdated in the future. So a link would be a better option. Let me know if that page answers that question. If it does then please feel free to edit the post and paste that link for others